# Deploy to Heroku NodeJS applications

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I tried my NodeJS web-app to deploy to Heroku, it gives me this error

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fierce-oasis-81492.git'
```

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the push with the **--force**, or **-f** option:

```
git push -f origin main
```